# using string split failed in hadoop mapper

Tags: java, hadoop

Below code is written in Mapper of Hadoop:

```
String[] s = value.toString().split("\\s+");
String date = s[1];
```

Error occurs in `s[1]`, `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.

Does regex not work in the hadoop?

Comment: what if `value.toString().split("\s+")` produces only one string? Or none? What's value?

Comment: I tried without the hadoop, it gives 28 elements by using split.(\\s+). For example, input "63891 20130101  5.102  -86.61   32.85    12.8     9.6    11.2    11.6    19.4 -9999.00 U -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -99.000 -99.000 -99.000 -99.000 -99.000 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0"

Comment: check your input files in hdfs and there are some lines with just one string without any say space or tab. Also print out that line by catching that error in your mapper just for debugging purpose.

Comment: One more thing, it's probably just a typo: you used only 1 backslash in the code you posted. Is that the case in the code you try to run?

Comment: Hi Lucas, I used double backslashes. Single one is not compiled.

Comment: could you try with value.toString().split(" ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to blank or space comes as a line, you have to filter it.

```
if(s.length>1){
String[] s = value.toString().split("\\s+");
String date = s[1];
}
```

your problem solution

// Map function:

```
  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
  //  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    //private Text word = new Text();
      double temp;

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      line=line.replaceAll("U","");
      int a=line.length();
      if(a>2)
      {
          int spec=line.indexOf(' ');
          String s=line.substring(spec,spec+9);
          String b=line.substring(spec+10,a);

      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(b);
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        {
            temp=Double.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken().toString());
        }
        output.collect(new Text(s), new DoubleWritable(temp));
      }
    }
    }
  }
```

// Reduce function:

```
  public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<DoubleWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        Double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        Double minvalue=Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Double a;
        while (values.hasNext()) 
        {
        a=values.next().get();
        maxValue = Math.max(maxValue,a);
        minvalue=Math.min(minvalue,a);
    if(maxValue>40)
        {
            output.collect(key,new DoubleWritable(maxValue));
        } 
   /*   if(minvalue<10)
        {
        output.collect(key, new DoubleWritable(a));
        } */

        }
    output.collect(new Text(key+"Max"), new DoubleWritable(maxValue));
    output.collect(new Text(key+"Min"),new DoubleWritable(minvalue));
    }
    }
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer.